# How to make atomic a nested iterative operation on ConcurrentHashMaps?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` **subscriptions**  that contain another object (**sessionCollection**) and I need to do the following iterative operation:

```
  subscriptions.values().forEach(sessionCollection -> 
     sessionCollection.removeAllSubscriptionsOfSession(sessionId));
```

where `sessionCollection.removeAllSubscriptionsOfSession` does another iterative operation over a collection (also `ConcurrentHashMap`) inside **sessionCollection**:

```
// inside SessionCollection:
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>> topicsToSessions = 
 new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void removeAllSubscriptionsOfSession(String sessionId) {
    // Remove sessions from all topics on record
    topicsToSessions.keySet().forEach(topicSessionKey ->
     removeTopicFromSession(sessionId, topicSessionKey));
}
```

What would be the steps to make this overall atomic operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` has batch operations (`forEach*()`), but they are not atomic with respect to the whole map. The only way to make atomic batch changes on a map is to implement all the necessary synchronization yourself. For instance, by using `synchronized` blocks explicitly or by creating a wrapper (or an extension)  for your map that will take care of synchronization where needed. In this case a simple `HashMap` will suffice since you have to do synchronization anyway:

```
public class SubscriptionsRegistry {
    private final Map<Integer, SessionCollection> map = new HashMap<>();

    public synchronized void removeSubscriptions(Integer sessionId) {
        map.values().forEach(...);
    }

    public synchronized void addSubscription(...) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

You'll also want to protect the topics-to-sessions maps (at least their modifiable versions) from leaking outside your `SubscriptionsRegistry`, so nobody is able to modify them without proper synchronization.

Comment: You could also use Collections.synchronizedMap and synchronize on the map itself, since synchronizedMap supports client side locking. The performance will be much worse than ConcurrentHashMap though. You need to decide whether ensuring that the entire map is locked is actually important for your logic, if so then there is no choice except to lock the entire map. In many cases this sort of locking is unnecessary.

Comment: I agree, `SynchronizedMap.forEach()` can be used to perform synchronized batch updates. Technically, it will be the same wrapper as I described, but with no operations semantics.